# Java. Нужно ли использовать конструктор, чтобы задать значения переменных класса по умолчанию?

Tags: java, конструктор

Нужно ли использовать конструктор, чтобы задать значения переменных класса по умолчанию, которые будут наследоваться объектами, или простое присваивание дает тот же эффект?

```
public class Vehicle {
  private String color;
  Vehicle() {
     color = "Red";
  }
}
```

---

```
public class Vehicle {
  private String color = "Red";

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> простое присваивание дает тот же эффект

Да, это просто синтаксический сахар. Но при одновременном использовании приоритет будет у конструктора (перепишет инициализатор).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!